# Add image or text onto all JSP pages through Struts or CSS

Tags: css, jsp, struts

I have a large number of JSP pages that need a small bit of static content added to them displayed in a fixed location.  The content can appear over current page content.  My question is, without making modifications to all 300 pages, is there a way to insert the content through Struts or CSS somehow?

For example, I want a logo to appear on all websites that I currently have, hovering at the bottom.

Note, I want to do this without making modifications to all 300 pages, and no, unfortunately the pages do not include menu header/footer files.  I DO have a CSS page that is used though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [sitemesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/index.html). Read the documentation for the full installation and config details, but basically, for example, you could create a "master" decorator (think of a decorator like a skin, or template) like this:

```
<div id="header">Whatever you want here</div>
<div class="docBody"><decorator:body /></div>
```

Next add this snippet to your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and then sitmesh will intercept the request, and wrap the "master" decorator around the result from each jsp. In other words, the contents of each jsp will be rendered into `<decorator:body>`.

Comment: Wow this sounds like exactly what I want to do.  Are you sure this method would work?  What issues might I run into?

Comment: I think there's a good chance it will work. Just a heads up, though, that depending on your comfort level with servlets and java frameworks, there might be a significant learning curve involved. If you've worked with SpringMVC, Struts2, or similar frameworks, then it should be doable, but I'd still suggest planning on a day or two for getting comfortable with sitemesh and the way opensymphony apis and libraries work. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Without making modifications to all 300 pages, your only bet is altering an existing CSS stylesheet.

To add an image, use `background-image` property.

```
#someId {
    background-image: url('images/foo.png');
}
```

To add some content, use `:before` or `:after` pseudoselector in combination with `content` property.

```
#someId:after {
    content: 'some content';
}
```

*Note: doesn't work in IE6/7, not sure if you'd like to still support that browser.*

As last resort you can grab JavaScript/[jQuery](http://jquery.com) to manipulate the HTML DOM tree (insert new elements). However, this still require an existing `<script>` file which is loaded on all pages.